# Firefox OS: How to implement mp4 and m3u8 streaming

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, firefox-os

I want to make a Firefox-OS application to stream video files in .mp4 (H.264) and later in .m3u8 format. With the `<video>` tag I tried the following code.

```
<video width="80%" height="80%" controls>
  <source src="http://example.com/video_podcast_h264_q10.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

In my GeeksPhone and in Firefox Browser on Mac I see only a black screen with the text saying: "no video with supported format and mime-type found"

On my server side app I placed a .htaccess file with: `AddType video/mp4 .mp4`

How do I implement live .mp4 streaming for Firefox-OS (i.e. for Geeks Phone) ?? Any suggestions or links to working code?

Comment: Does it has something to do [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4)?

Comment: This sounds not good :-(  "Firefox supports H.264 on Windows 7 and later since version 21. Partial support for Firefox refers to the lack of support in OSX & Linux platforms". Does it mean Firefox-OS does not support .mp4 (H.264)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Apps/Tips_and_techniques#Media_presentation):

> Currently, for security reasons, the h.264 decoder on Firefox OS devices is only available to privileged code. Because of that, you can't use the  element to present h.264 content at this time. You can, however, use a Web Activity. Here's a code snippet that can help:

```
var activity = new MozActivity({
  name: "view",
  data: {
    type: [
      "video/webm",
      "video/mp4",
      "video/3gpp",
      "video/youtube"
    ],
    url: "http://example.com/myvideo.mp4"
  }
});
```

I've read [elsewhere](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/969229) that there may be size limits, so you may want to experiment with that.

More information on Web Activities here:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/web-activities-firefox-os-the-platform-html5-deserves/

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you @brianchirls ! It works perfect on my geeksphone device. Note: In the Firefox-OS Simulator it is not working, you need a real device for this.  
'Is there a way to play .m3u8 live streams too?'

Comment: .m3u8 is a text-format playlist, so I suppose you could XHR it and parse it yourself. Don't forget CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You can take Tizen's code for your idea, because Tizen pronounced support HLS(m3u8). Firefox os didn't plan to support HLS(m3u8), seems cared about license.

If you want improve the product out, maybe change your device to support Android or Tizen is better way.

Comment: Thanks jian but I'm already using Android and iOS where everything works fine. Firefox OS sounds promising but I didn't get HLS to work :-(